# in genetic algorithm, how to initialize population and how to determine the length of chromosomes if there is no constraints?

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

For example, how to minimize x^2 when x ranges from -inf to inf?
How to pick initial length of chromosomes?
How to determine initial population?
Can I do in a guided way instead of initializing randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genetic algorithms normally have a fixed length in the chromosome representation, if the length will vary we are talking more about Genetic Programming.

Anyway. I don't know if there is a rule on the initial length, but you should think of a size that allows the individuals to offer good initial results, but is not very large. You need to remember that GA/GP tend to present [Bloat](http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/staff/poli/gp-field-guide/113Bloat.html).

Initial population should be the largest you can use and still be able to finish your executions in a reasonable amount of time given your computational power available. In my experience more is always better.

About the initialization, there are certainly several seeding techniques, [this paper](http://www.enggjournals.com/ijet/docs/IJET13-05-03-387.pdf) enumerates some of them, you should be able to find more information about each of them: Nearest Neighbor (NN), Gene Bank (GB), Selective Initialization (SI), Sorted population (SP).

For all the questions above, the best way is to experiment a lot and figure out what works best for your problem, your implementation. For instance: in a system I have the best solution usually sits around 70 nodes; after a lot of experimentation I found a sweet spot of initial individuals of 45 nodes, which worked better than initializing at 30 or 60.